# Getting lyrics of song from genius lyrics with beautifulsoup │python 3.8

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the lyrics for a song from genius lyrics using beautifulsoup but when trying to print out the lyrics, I get no output. Here is my code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
songURL = requests.get("https://genius.com/Marshmello-and-bastille-happier-lyrics")
song = songURL.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(song, 'lxml')
lyrics = soup.find_all("section")
for lyr in lyrics:
    for lyr1 in lyrics.select("p"):
        print(lyr1.text)
```

Why is this not working, can somebody please look into this as I have been trying to do this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the server returns two version of the page: in one version there are tags with `class="song_body-lyrics"`, in other version with `class="Lyrics__Container..."`.

This script tries to handle both cases:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://genius.com/Marshmello-and-bastille-happier-lyrics'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.select('div[class^="Lyrics__Container"], .song_body-lyrics p'):
    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
    if t:
        print(t)
```

Prints:

```
[Intro]
Lately, I've been, I've been thinking
I want you to be happier, I want you to be happier
[Verse 1]

...and so on.
```

Comment: so it picks either of the matches? a class that starts with Lyrics__Container under the div tag or p tag after song_body-lyrics class? wow, this so powerful.

Comment: @politicalscientist Yes, it's CSS selector with comma `,` (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp). It's good that BeautifulSoup supports it, very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
songURL = requests.get("https://genius.com/Marshmello-and-bastille-happier-lyrics")
song = songURL.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(song, 'lxml')
final_lyrics = []
lyrics = soup.find('div', {'class': "lyrics"})
lyrics = lyrics.find_all('p')
for i in lyrics:
    final_lyrics.append(i.text)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get all texts those are in a specific div. you can find that specific div with `devtools` or `viewsource` in your browser. here that specific div is `<div class='lyrics'>` the unique feature of this div is its class, that is class 'lyrics' so we should find this specific div in HTML and then print all texts in that div.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://alirezaarabi.com/view-source_https___genius.com_Alessia-cara-ready-lyrics.html').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.title.string)

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lyrics'):
    print(div.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at the actual HTML source code, there are no `section` tags. Here's what the structure actually looks like:

```
<div class="song_body column_layout" initial-content-for="song_body">
  <div class="column_layout-column_span column_layout-column_span--primary">
    <div class="song_body-lyrics">
      
        <h2 class="text_label text_label--gray text_label--x_small_text_size u-top_margin">Happier Lyrics</h2>
      
      <div initial-content-for="lyrics">
        <div class="lyrics">
          
            <!--sse-->
            <p>[Intro]<br>
Lately, I've been, I've been thinking<br>
I want you to be happier, I want you to be happier<br>
<br>
...
```